# (R) How do I group by and then summarise by each element of a column, rather than the column itself?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-structures

I have a data frame like

```
df <- tribble(~Name, ~Numeric, ~String,
              "Python", 9, c("ABCD", "A", "AB"),
              "R", 14, c("XYZ", "Q", "ABCD"),
              "Java", 3, c("AB", "A"),
              "SQL", 6, c("AB", "A", "XYZ"),
              "Excel", 20, c("AB", "Q"))
```

I want to be able to 'group_by' in such a way that I am able to summarize data by each individual string (such as "ABCD", or "A").

If I simply try to group_by the string column, I wind up with these results which are not useful to me:

```
df_grouped <- df %>% group_by(String) %>% summarize(mean_numeric = mean(Numeric))


      String                    mean_numeric
1   c("ABCD", "A", "AB")          9
2   c("XYZ", "Q", "ABCD")         14
3   c("AB", "A")                  3
4   c("AB", "A", "XYZ")           6
5   c("AB", "Q")                  20
```

I would rather need a summary like this (taking a mean of the numerics for all rows where the elements are located):

```
string_element               mean_numeric         
"ABCD"                          11.5               
"A"                              6
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Your data is nested. Use `unnest` before:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  unnest(String) %>% 
  group_by(String) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(Numeric, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
  String  mean
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 A        6  
2 AB       9.5
3 ABCD    11.5
4 Q       17  
5 XYZ     10
```